# Is there a way to change the font size unit for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I think I already know the answer, but I have to ask. So we developed an update which includes an option for users to have larger text size. Apparently, they didn't notice this until now because they want the font size to be the same on smaller phones and big phones. (even though the app had different font sizes before we did this, but i digress). So we see that the same number of words is consistent whether it's an iPhone 5 or iPhone 6S+. And I understand we just give the FontSize attribute a value and the phone determines how big it should be.

Is there any way to force it to be the same font size no matter what kind of phone it is? Before I get backlash, I am not setting a different `FontSize` value. It's the same, but depending on how big or small your actual phone is, it might APPEAR to be bigger or smaller. Which we would like to do away with.

I also understand that `FontSize` uses `points` for iOS, and `DP` for Android. So I guess the only way to achieve what management wants is to (if we can) change the unit to pixels or something? Obviously, I'm pretty confused because this seems to be working as expected, just a really odd request from management which I hope someone has some insight on?

Comment: Are you using a custom font? By default iOS uses Helvetica Neue (or San Francisco depending on the iOS version) and Android uses Roboto. So you might need to pick the same font for both platforms to start with.

Comment: It's not the font that's the issue, but the font size. And not even about different platforms, but different phones of iOS. For example, iPhone 6+ the SAME font size looks different on iPhone 6S or iPhone 5. Want to try to get them to be the same, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using a value converter that looked at the type of device and scaled it appropriately. Not the best way, but it works.

Comment: @Shaegorath I no longer work at this company and don't have the code :(. Although, it's simple logic. You make the font-size go through a value converter, and inside the value converter you check for the device type. If its apple, you do one thing, if android, you do another, if windows you do another..etc. This might be good reference as well (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96529/font-size)